# AWS CLI EMR keyname doesn't recognize my access key, same region confirmed

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, key, amazon-emr

to start EMR, is KeyName the same as the access key string? I am using accesskey as the arg here: but EMR doesn't accept the access key. I don't see where I can provide a name other than access key:

aws emr create-cluster --name "Kens Test EMR Cluster" ^
--region us-east-2 --release-label emr-5.36.1 --applications Name=Spark ^
--ec2-attributes KeyName=**<Access Key String Numbers**>^
--instance-type m5.xlarge --instance-count 3  --use-default-roles

AWS EMR docs don't say if it's actually expecting Access Key so not sure

Comment: No, `KeyName` is for the name of the SSH key, not the AWS Access key. You don't need to specify the latter anywhere - refer to the AWS CLI documentation on authenticating